# GoogleCalendar Datekey

Tags: javascript, html, google-calendar-api

Google is using an unique DateKeys for each days in the GoogleCalendar HTML e.g.

```html
<div 
  data-datekey="129"
  role="gridcell" 
  tabindex="-1" 
  jsname="RjPD4e" 
  aria-labelledby="tsc-0" 
  data-column-index="0"  
  data-principal-ids="amFuLm5pY2tsYXNAbmFtaWNzLmNvbQ" 
  class="YvjgZe Qbfsob">
```

Is there any formular to calculate the date for a given datekey?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the `dateKey` represents the days since `1.1.1970` in a format optimised for byte shifting.

One year has `2^9` (`512`) days.
One month has `2^5` (`32`) days.

To calculate the `datekey` for `01.01.1970` you would calculate:

> `0` years (since 1970) `* 512`
> `+ 1` month `* 32`
> `+ 1` day
> `= 33`

To calculate the `datekey` for `01.01.2000` you would calculate:

> `30` years (since 1970) `* 512`
> `+ 1` month `* 32`
> `+ 1` day
> `= 15393`

To calculate the date for a given date key you can do the opposite.
A modulo calculation could look like the following:

```
function getDate(dateKey) {
  const yearOffset = (dateKey - 32) % 512;
  const year = (dateKey - 32 - yearOffset) / 512;
  const day = yearOffset % 32;
  const month = (yearOffset - day) / 32;
  return new Date(year + 1970, month, day);
}
```

Does anyone know why they came up with such a logic?

Answer (score 6):

In response to @jantimon's answer: I guess they had to do a lot of calculations with dates and wanted it to be efficient.

The odd thing is that if you look at the little calendar in the sidebar, rather than using a `data-datekey` attribute, it uses `data-date` with a `YYYYMMDD` format.

Anyway, I rewrote your conversion function using bitwise operations, since it's easier to read this way.

```
function datekeyToDate(key) {
    /* # BITS: [year_rel(6)][month(4)][day(5)] */
    const day = key & 0b11111;
    const month = (key>>5) & 0b1111;
    const year_rel = (key>>9);
    const year = 1970 + year_rel;
    return new Date(year, month, day);
}

function dateToDatekey(date) {
    const y = date.getFullYear() - 1970;
    const m = date.getMonth()+1;    /* getMonth() returns 0-based index */
    const d = date.getDate();
    return (y<<9) + (m<<5) + d;
}
```

Comment: Would it be realiable to create a schedule calendar using this approach? I wonder why there is not much about such solutions for dates. It seems more efficient than most forms I've seen.